# Are invalid card numbers under PCI compliance

Tags: pci-dss, credit-card

If a merchant sends an invalid card number to the bank, will the bank have to secure the information to be PCI compliant?

Answer (score 2):

If a non-valid card was exposed, who is at risk and whose date has been exposed? Since its not a valid card, there is no "card holder".

In the intro the the [PCI DSS 3.0](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3.pdf%E2%80%8E):

> The Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard (PCI DSS) was
>   developed to encourage and enhance cardholder data security and
>   facilitate  the broad adoption of consistent data security measures
>   globally. PCI DSS provides a baseline of technical and operational
>   requirements  designed to protect cardholder data.

If it's an invalid code because the LUHN does not pass, it does not start with a valid bank identifier, it cannot be issued to a client. It's likely not on any piece of plastic with a card brand logo. PCI only [applies to cards with a brand logo](http://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pcifaqs.php#9).

However, if the same source (merchant) can send both invalid and invalid cards, it would have to assume the card numbers are valid until checked, which means the normal encryption protections, etc would need to be followed. If for some reason you had a separate channel for invalid numbers, non-issuable test numbers, those should not fall under PCI, however, with everything in PCI, always check your friendly QSA.

Comment: PCIDSS aside, common sense suggests these numbers be treated as sensitive anyway.  It isn't exceptionally difficult to guess what the correct number might have been in the event of a single-digit transposition or an invalid BIN.

Comment: I agree, you would not know until after you handled it that it was invalid. You make a good point about it easily be calculated if its a one-off type error. It's a little hard to understand the exact scenario the OP is making or if this is just a "thought" question.

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to answer your question with a different example.

Any PCI service provider (e.g. processors, fraud services, etc) is likely to use test card numbers.  Test card numbers will have valid [Luhn Algorithm (mod 10)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) numbers and even valid IINs (apparently [BIN is now called IIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_card_number)!  Who knew?).  The associated name and expiration information, if any are used, will be made up and presumed not to match actual issued card/name pairs.

They may very well be real card numbers.  It might just so happen that the test card 4111111111111111 with name "Test User" has the same number as the real and issued card 4111111111111111 "Randy Waterhouse".  When you generate rule-compliant test numbers, there's nothing preventing you from hitting the same number as a valid card.

The PCI-DSS is not explicit about the status of these numbers - in general, numerically valid test numbers are discouraged via lack of approval or guidance from the card brands.  In real terms, however, they do not fall into PCI scope and requirements - they don't need to be encrypted on disk, for example.

But here's the key -

When the QSA comes to audit the organization, they're going to search for card numbers.  And they're going to find those test numbers.  And they're going to require some sort of convincing that they are, in fact, test numbers and not valid issued number instances.  They'll want to see clearly invalid names, or auditing and logging that convinces them of the bogus provenance of the numbers, or some evidence that the organization has a way to keep test data separate from real data.

So, just because test numbers don't fall under PCI scope, doesn't mean you can ignore PCI with regards to them.  Just as @eric-g said, the organization needs to  "assume the card numbers are valid until checked" - and if they're numerically valid numbers, "checked" means more.